# Count data from a table excluding duplicates

Tags: python, django, count, models

I need to count elements from a table. The problem is that I do have a solution for this, but I'm using a function that deletes duplicates from the table and then I can get the count without issue (but it takes a while to process) This is an example of my model/table:

[image]

If I do a count from this I will get the following result:
3 Shipped, 4 allocated, 2 No status, 1 Loaded.

What I need is to get the following result: 2 Shipped (ignoring 1 duplicate), 1 Allocated (ignoring 3 duplicate), 2 No status(There is no duplicate), 1 Loaded.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Can you share what code you've tried and what you've done? It will be easier to answer when we know how the data is being read and stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL you can use the following to use `DISTINCT ON`

```
Model.objects.order_by('field').dictinct('field').count()
```

If you are using MySQL you can use

```
Model.objects.order_by('field').aggregate(count=Count('field', distinct=True))['count']
```

You need to `order_by` the field you pass to distinct, [there is more information in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

Comment: So, as an example if I want to count how many shipped I have based on their SOSS, the model query should be: Model.objects.order_by('Shipped').aggregate(count=Count('Shipped', distinct=True))['count'] ? or were do I declare to skip a duplicated SOSS.

Comment: You would do `Model.objects.filter(status='Shipped').order_by('soss').aggregate(count=Count('soss', distinct=True))['count']`

Comment: shipped_unique = ShipmentView.objects.filter(status='Shipped Complete').order_by('sales_order').aggregate(count=ShipmentView('sales_order', distinct=True))['count'] ?

Comment: I get error on this count=Count('s‌​oss', distinct=True)) :((

Comment: You've used `ShipmentV‌​iew` instead of `Count`?

Comment: still having issues with this

Comment: Have you tried `shipped_unique = ShipmentView.objects.filter(status='Shipped Complete').aggregate(count=Count('sales_order', distinct=True))['count']`

Comment: >>> unique = ShipmentView.objects.filter(original_fcd_date=day).filter(df_status="No 3A5").aggregate(count=Count('sales_order', distinct=True))['count']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Count' is not defined

Comment: and if I change Count for the name of the model I get this error

Comment: >>> unique = ShipmentView.objects.filter(original_fcd_date=day).filter(df_status="No 3A5").aggregate(count=ShipmentView('sales_order', distinct=True))['count']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 555, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'distinct' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Im an idiot forgot to declare from django.db.models import Count, :O